# Can I lower the API level(minSDK) of my app after publishing on Google Play?

Tags: android-manifest, google-play, android

the api level of my published app right now is API 8 level and i was thinking of lowering it to 7 for 2.1 users, is it still possible to do it? after publishing the app?

i already tried lowering the minsdkversion and the target sdkversion in the manifest to 7 but eclipse still won't detect my phone as a compatible device for the package, my phone is acer liquid e 2.1.

and there is this file below the manifet the default.properties file and there is a target=android-8 statement in it, i try changing it to 7 and upon saving errors appear through out my xml files, is there a way for me to change it to API 7 so upon the update of the app to the market it will be now available to 2.1 users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you can absolutely update your app to target a lower API level. The steps are as follows:

1. Right-click on your project
2. Click on Properties
3. Click the Android tab.
4. Target the API level you desire.
5. Make sure your manifest targets uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
6. Increment your version in the manifest so it is considered an update. Something like:

android:versionName="2.0.0"
    android:versionCode="2"

That should do it!

If you continue to have compiler errors, read them. Are you using something like Google APIs anywhere in your app? If so, you obviously have to target Google APIs, etc. Are you using any 2.2-specific features? If you answered "no" to both these questions, you should be just fine.

Comment: Is this still valid, can we lower mindsdk version after publishing , year 2020

Answer (score 0):

> the api level of my published app right now is API 8 level and i was
>   thinking of lowering it to 7 for 2.1 users, is it still possible to do
>   it? after publishing the app?

Yes it is possible to do it.

> and there is this file below the manifet the default.properties file
>   and there is a target=android-8 statement in it, i try changing it to
>   7 and upon saving errors appear through out my xml files

Change **"match_parent"** values to **"fill_parent"** in all your **layout.xml** files.